# Write result of a loop into a table knime

Tags: knime

right now I am writing a loop in knime and the result for every row is saved into a csv file , which is quite slow as my disk is quite slow. The result looks like this (for one row):

```
columnA
"A"
"B"
"BB"
```

My knime workflow looks like this:
[image]

How can I replace the csv write node, that I get a big table like this:

```
Rownumber columnA
1         "A"
1         "B"
1         "BB"
2         "C"
```

The idea is that I save the csv add the end (after the loop) to jsut have once the speed of my disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Loop End (2 ports)` node, and connect the second input port to the output of your `Concatenate (Optional in)` node.  Then plate the `CSV Writer` after the loop end, attached to the 2nd output port.
Alternatively, if you are not using the output from 'Node 90', then just connect the `Concatenate (Optional in)` node output to the `Loop End` input, and then put the `CSV Writer` after the loop end.

[image]

Comment: any chance to track the current iteration of the loop? to keep an eye, where the loop is already right now?

Comment: You can pause the loop at the end of the current iteration to see what that iteration looks like (right-click on the loop end and select 'Pause Loop' - you can then resume or step through another iteration).  Also, any node within the loop should show the 'current iteration' in the flow variables tab of it's output